# How to find the position vector of S

Tags: vectors

$OPQR$ is a parallelogram, with $O$ the origin. $M$ is the midpoint of $PQ$. $OM$ and $RQ$ are extended to meet as $S$. $\vec{OP}=\mathbf{p}$ and $\vec{OR}=\mathbf{r}$.

[image]

---

In this question I have to find the position vector of $S$.
I know that $\displaystyle \vec {OM}=\mathbf{p}+\frac{\mathbf r}{2}$. First I considered Pythagorean theorem, but it turned out that there is no right angle here hence I got bewildered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the vectors and use the geometry that you might have already learned: $\triangle{OPM}$ and $\triangle{SQM}$ are clearly similar. We’re given that $QM=PM$, therefore they’re congruent, and so $SQ=OP$. Now use the parallelogram rule for vector addition to determine the position vector for $Q$, from which you can get to $S$ using the above information.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Note that $\,s = \mu m = \mu (p + r/2)\,$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ because $S$ lies on $OM$, and $\,s = \lambda p +r \,$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ because $S$ lies on $RQ$. Since $p, r$ are  linearly independent:

$$
\lambda p + r = \mu (p + r/2) \quad\iff\quad \lambda = \mu\,, \;\; 1 = \mu / 2 
$$

Comment: I'm still in high school so easier symbols would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Murad I am using $x$ for the position vector $\vec{OX}$ of a point $X$, just like the problem uses $p$ for $\vec{OP}\,$.

Comment: But i still don't understand μ∈ℝ

Comment: @Murad $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ simply means that $\mu$ is a real number. Two non-zero vectors are collinear iff one can be obtained from the other by multiplying with a real constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using ratios on an $X$-figure:

$$\frac{|PM|}{|OP|}= \frac{|MQ|}{|QS|}\stackrel{|PM|=|MQ|=\frac{1}{2}|PQ|}{\Rightarrow} |OP| = |QS|$$

As $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{QS}$ lie on parallel sides in a parallelogram and have the same direction you get
$$\vec{OP} = \vec{QS} = p$$

Obviously we have also 
$$\vec{PM} = \vec{MQ} =\frac{1}{2}r$$
So, 
$$\vec{OS} = p+\frac{1}{2}r+\frac{1}{2}r+p = 2p+r$$